# Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type) Grayed Out in Lyx

Tags: amsmath, lyx

I am using Lyx with AMS article document class. Right now all my theorems, lemmas, propositions, etc. are numbered with the same counter. I would instead like them to be numbered by type. For example, Prop 1, Prop 2, [then] Theorem 1.

I gathered that I need to change something in modules, by adding Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type). However, the button to add this is grayed out. How do I activiate Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type)?

[image]

Possibly [related](https://lyx-users.lyx.narkive.com/r7iNZ9xv/using-theorems-numbered-by-type-with-named-theorems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Theorems (AMS)" and "Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type)" are substitutes. They can't be used together. So on the right pane of the dialog, select "Theorems (AMS)" and click on "Delete"; and then on the left pane select "Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type)".